# Windows tree-like command that can work over the network share

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares, tree

I need to obtain a folder tree structure on the Windows network share. I know that there is `tree` command, but it works only with drives. Is there analog that works with network shares? I.e. what I want to do is something like `network-tree \\myserver\myshare`. Is it possible in some way?
p.s. There may be workaround to mount network share as drive and run regular `tree` command, but I am wondering is it possible to do that without mapping a network share to a drive letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TREE` command in Windows 10 will accept a UNC pathname and return the desired results, but there is an undocumented caveat: It will apparently NOT cross a mount point (e.g., if you have a filesystem `\\SHARE1\STUFF` with a mount point `MORESTUF` (`\\SHARE1\STUFF\MORESTUF`), `TREE \\SHARE1\STUFF\MORESTUF` will throw an error).